# Geometric Interpretation of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Is there is geometric proof of the  [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) with 2 terms (not the vector one)?

$$(a² + b²)(c² + d²) ≥ (ac + bd)² $$

A geometric representation of this identity would also mean the same:

$$(a² + b²)(c² + d²) = (ac + bd)² + (bc - ad)²$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to use geometry for real numbers?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Can't we do something like this? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AM_GM_inequality_animation.gif

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this is the best I can squeeze out of my brain right now:

[image]

The parallelogram inside of the rectangle has side lengths $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$, and so, its area is at most

$$\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}.$$

On the other hand, its area can be computed by

$$(b+c)(a+d)-ab-cd=ac+bd.$$

Comment: Thanks, I got it. How did you come up with this?

Comment: @Shub, Pretty weak at elementary geometry, I was actually motivated by linear algebra. Indeed, $$ac+bd=\det\begin{pmatrix}c&-d\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$$ is the signed area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors $(c,-d)$ and $(b,a)$. And this is exactly the parallelogram in the figure if its leftmost vertex is chosen as the origin. Then I reverse-engineered this observation in terms of geometry.

Comment: @Shub I hope now do you see that it's impossible? Where you saw the segment with a negative length?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, A geometric "proof" is just an informal way of visualizing a maths formula that makes it easy to remember. Don't take it so seriously. Of course, we can't show negative nos. in that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Denote Area of a polygon $S_{polygon}$.
As shown in the picture by the red lines, $$S_{MNPQ} = {1\over 2} S_{XYZW}$$, the latter is same as $S_{XMPW}$.

Therefore
$$S_{MNP}+S_{MQP} = S_{XMPW}$$

$$S_{MNP} = S_{XMQ}+S_{QPW}$$

$$MN\cdot NP \geq MN\cdot NP\cdot \sin({\angle MNP})=2S_{MNP} = 2S_{XMQ}+2S_{QPW}=ac+bd$$

$$MN^2\cdot NP^2 \geq (ac+bd)^2$$

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\geq (ac+bd)^2$$

The equality will become true when $\angle MNP$ is ninty degree.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality reduces to:

$$(ad)^2+(bc)^2\ge 2abcd$$

wlog let $bc=ad+k, k\ge0$. Then:

$$(ad)^2+(ad+k)^2\ge 2ad(ad+k)$$

$$2adk+k^2\ge 2adk$$

$$k^2\ge 0$$

So there isn't much need for a geometric proof.

Comment: I know the algebraic one. Thanks for your time!